# Inside boundaries

Tags: fluid-layout, fluid-dynamics

I'm using this [article](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/stam/reality/Research/pdf/GDC03.pdf) to write a fluid simulation application.
I can't manage to implement the inside boundaries. As far as i know when I'm setting the boundaries (in the **set_bnd** function) for each cell that is inside the boundary I should calculate the average value from the adjacent non-boundary cells like this:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
  for (j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
  {
     if (isBoundary(i,j)
     {
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
        if (!isBoundary(i+1,j) {
           sum += x[i+1][j];
        }
        if (!isBoundary(i-1,j) {
           sum += x[i-1][j];
        }
        if (!isBoundary(i,j+1) {
           sum += x[i][j+1];
        }
        if (!isBoundary(i,j-1) {
           sum += x[i-1][j];
        }
        x[i][j] = sum / 4;
     }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the smoke is absorbed and disappears in contact with boundary surface.
My math background is not sufficient to understand every part of the calculation, so I'll be very grateful if someone points me the right direction.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more in detail please? `set_bnd` is defined in the paper. What is your code supposed to do for which cells? Cells adjacent to boundary cells (meaning cells with at least one face equivalent to the wall boundary) aren't supposed to be handled specially as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to explain further.
*insideBound* is array (1 - boundary, 0 - empty, the fluid can pass trough)

```
#define FOR_EACH_CELL for ( i=1 ; i<=N ; i++ ) { for ( j=1 ; j<=N ; j++ ) {


void set_bnd ( int N, int b, float * x, int * insideBound )
{
int i, j;
float sum;
int count;

for ( i=1 ; i<=N ; i++ ) {
    x[IX(0  ,i)] = b==1 ? -x[IX(1,i)] : x[IX(1,i)];
    x[IX(N+1,i)] = b==1 ? -x[IX(N,i)] : x[IX(N,i)];
    x[IX(i,0  )] = b==2 ? -x[IX(i,1)] : x[IX(i,1)];
    x[IX(i,N+1)] = b==2 ? -x[IX(i,N)] : x[IX(i,N)];
}
x[IX(0  ,0  )] = 0.5f*(x[IX(1,0  )]+x[IX(0  ,1)]);
x[IX(0  ,N+1)] = 0.5f*(x[IX(1,N+1)]+x[IX(0  ,N)]);
x[IX(N+1,0  )] = 0.5f*(x[IX(N,0  )]+x[IX(N+1,1)]);
x[IX(N+1,N+1)] = 0.5f*(x[IX(N,N+1)]+x[IX(N+1,N)]);

if (!b) return;

FOR_EACH_CELL
    sum = 0.0f;
    count = 0;
    if (insideBound[IX(i,j)] == 1)
    {
        if (insideBound[IX(i-1,j)] != 1)
        {
            count++;
            sum = sum + x[IX(i-1,j)];
        }

        if (insideBound[IX(i+1,j)] != 1)
        {
            count++;
            sum = sum + x[IX(i+1,j)];
        }

        if (insideBound[IX(i,j-1)] != 1)
        {
            count++;
            sum = sum + x[IX(i, j-1)];
        }

        if (insideBound[IX(i,j+1)] != 1)
        {
            count++;
            sum = sum + x[IX(i, j+1)];
        }

        if (count > 0)
        {
            x[IX(i,j)] = -sum / count;
        } else {
            x[IX(i,j)]  = 0;
        }


    }

END_FOR

}
```

**Per book (working):**
In the first loop are set top, right, bottom and left boundary cells. 
Since for them there is only one adjacent cell that is not bound the cell get its value. (I don't know why its opposite for U and the same value for V)

After the first loop, the corner boundary values are set. Here they get average values from their adjacent cells (i guess since there is no adjacent cell that is not boundary they use boundary cells).

**Mine, not working properly**:
if (!b) return - ignores calculations for density and updates only velocity.
The loop calculates the values for all boundary cells (again, average values from the adjacent cells that are not boundaries themselves).
I get almost realistic result from this methods, but there is big loses in the density and some bugs with too big boundaries where the fluid disappears completely.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution, here it is for potential people with the same problem

```
void set_bnd ( int N, int b, float * x, int * insideBound )
{
    int i, j;
    float sum, tmp;
    int count;

    for ( i=1 ; i<=N ; i++ ) {
        x[IX(0  ,i)] = b==1 ? -x[IX(1,i)] : x[IX(1,i)];
        x[IX(N+1,i)] = b==1 ? -x[IX(N,i)] : x[IX(N,i)];
        x[IX(i,0  )] = b==2 ? -x[IX(i,1)] : x[IX(i,1)];
        x[IX(i,N+1)] = b==2 ? -x[IX(i,N)] : x[IX(i,N)];
    }
    x[IX(0  ,0  )] = 0.5f*(x[IX(1,0  )]+x[IX(0  ,1)]);
    x[IX(0  ,N+1)] = 0.5f*(x[IX(1,N+1)]+x[IX(0  ,N)]);
    x[IX(N+1,0  )] = 0.5f*(x[IX(N,0  )]+x[IX(N+1,1)]);
    x[IX(N+1,N+1)] = 0.5f*(x[IX(N,N+1)]+x[IX(N+1,N)]);

    if (!b) return;

    for ( i=1 ; i<=N ; i++ ) {
        for ( j=1 ; j<=N ; j++ ) {
            sum = 0.0f;
            count = 0;
            if (insideBound[IX(i,j)] == 1)
            {
                if (insideBound[IX(i-1,j)] != 1)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (b == 2)
                        tmp = -x[IX(i-1,j)];
                    else 
                        tmp = x[IX(i-1,j)];

                    sum = sum + tmp;
                }

                if (insideBound[IX(i+1,j)] != 1)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (b == 2)
                        tmp = -x[IX(i+1,j)];
                    else
                        tmp =  x[IX(i+1,j)];
                    sum = sum + tmp;
                } 

                if (insideBound[IX(i,j-1)] != 1)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (b == 1)
                        tmp = - x[IX(i, j-1)];
                    else 
                        tmp =  x[IX(i, j-1)];
                    sum = sum + tmp;
                } 

                if (insideBound[IX(i,j+1)] != 1)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (b == 1)
                        tmp = -x[IX(i, j+1)];
                    else 
                        tmp = x[IX(i, j+1)];
                    sum = sum + tmp;
                } 

                if (count > 0)
                {
                    x[IX(i,j)] = -sum / count;
                } else {
                    x[IX(i,j)]  = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**insideBound** is boolean array (0,1) which indicates the cells that are boundaries. Works with one or more boundary areas, but they should be at least 3 cells wide and high.